# .net web api Http post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't have much experience with .NET Web Api, but i've been working with it for a course project.The application works fine, but the thing i'm struggling with now,testing POST-controllers through fidler.
Give me guide that how to test wep api http post method The only problem for me is when it comes to test the POST method.
I recently seen many articles and apply on it but they never works still..

Any help would be appreciatiable:

My controller looks like:

```
public class DonationCausesController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /DonationCauses/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void addcauses(Causes causes) 
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=Lenovo-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Donation_db;Integrated Security=True";  
        //SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblEmployee (EmployeeId,Name,ManagerId) Values (@EmployeeId,@Name,@ManagerId)", myConnection);  
        string approving_status="not approved";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();  
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Volunteer_problem(Volunteer_name,Volunteer_cause,Cause_location,Volunteer_contact,Approved) Values (@Volunteer_name,@Volunteer_cause,@Cause_location,@Volunteer_contact,@Approved)";  
        sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;  


        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Volunteer_name", causes.volunteer_name);  
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Volunteer_cause", causes.volunteer_cause);  
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cause_location", causes.cause_location);  
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Volunteer_contact", causes.volunteer_contact);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Approved", approving_status);  
        myConnection.Open();  
        int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Properties class :

```
public class Causes
{
    public string volunteer_name { get; set; }
    public string volunteer_cause { get; set; }
    public string cause_location { get; set; }
    public int volunteer_contact { get; set; }
}
```

[fidler looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUyUM.png)

Comment: Try PostMan with Chrome. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

In fiddler's request composer, you have two parts: Request's headers and request's body. In `Get` requests, body is obviously empty. But in `Post` and `Put` you can specify the contents of the body. For your specific problem, you can achieve your goal by one of two ways
1- Use Json in `Content-Type` header in request headers. If you take this route, your request headers will look something like

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Authorization: your auth token if using one
Host: localhost:61026
Content-Length: 788
Content-Type: application/json
```

and request body should look something like

```
{"volunteer_name": "good name", "volunteer_cause": "good cause", 
"cause_location" :"my location", "volunteer_contact" : 5}
```

2- If you are using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as `content-Type`. Your headers will look something like

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
    Authorization: your auth token if using one
    Host: localhost:61026
    Content-Length: 788
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and your request body will look like

```
volunteer_name=good name&volunteer_cause=good_cause&volunteer_location=my location&volunteer_contact=5
```

Please note that you don't need to specify the `content-length` header with request, it will be automatically calculated by fiddler

Comment: Brother i written the same as u describe but still no reponse ...!

Comment: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found                                                                                 this will show when i press execute button

Comment: here is detail :{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:19930/api/DonationCauses/addcauses'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'DonationCauses'."}

Comment: There has to be a problem with your routes then

Comment: BTW, You need to inherit from `ApiController` to create web api. From your code, it seems you are inheriting from `Controller` which is in asp.net mvc paradigm

Comment: ok thanks.i have done it but now HTTP/1.1 204 No Content is shown..!!

Comment: It will show No Content because you method is returning `void`. Convert it to something else like `string` and return "Hello world" from method once the db stuff is completed and then you can see the result in fiddler that you returned from your method

Comment: Brother but the question is why the data are not inserted in db..?

Comment: Looking at your code, the data should be inserted in db or at least you should get an exception. Trying placing a breakpoint in the method and run it statement by statement and see if there is any exception?